# How to provide separate javascript files for each divs in one html page

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if it's possible, but I wanna ask from experienced people first.

I'm building a simple web game in one HTML file, I have a javascript file for it already. Now I want to add another game (in another div) in the same HTML file (because I want the game to be a SPA 'sort of') but I want to use a separate Javascript file for the new game (that's inside the HTML file).

My question is...is it possible to have separate JS files for each DIV in one HTML file? or is there a way to divide JS codes of each DIV in a single JS file?

What I'm thinking about the latter is that the code will be too long thereby causing a slow application (I'm not sure if this is valid tho), and if it is not valid, how can I achieve this?.

Comment: You can load and append new JS files to the head. on demand

Comment: This question is very broad. If the JS for one game is very large, inserting the JS for two games in a single page might not be the best idea, as it'll take much more time to load the page for people that just want one of the games. One solution is to load the JS dynamically, based on the game you want to play. You could present the user with a list of games, then download the JS for the chosen game and init it. Regarding the question of JS 'for a DIV', JavaScript is global to the page. What you can do, is to render the results of the execution of certain JavaScript code in a DIV.

Comment: Alright @OscarPaz, can you please demonstrate how to present the user with a list of games, then download the JS for the chosen game and init it

Comment: That's a lot of work and now I don't have the time. But you can find lots of info about how to add scripts dynamically to a page. Just have a game definition for each game, that contains the URL of the game JS, and add it to the page. Once it's dowloaded, use the objects defined in the script to start the game. If  you're going to   develop a game, surely you know how to do this, as it is way easier!

Comment: Alright, thank you @OscarPaz